# Magento2.4.5: How to add custom text fields on checkout page?

Tags: magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2

I want to add custom text fields on the checkout page and those fields' values should be saved in **sales_order** and **sales_order_item** table
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2.4.5, you can add custom text fields on the checkout page by creating a custom module and using layout updates and template files. Here are the general steps you can follow:

1. Create a new module and register it in the `app/code` directory.
2. In the module's `etc/module.xml` file, add the `<sequence>` tag to depend on the `Magento_Checkout` module.
3. Create a new layout file, `checkout_index_index.xml` in the `view/frontend/layout` directory of your module, and use it to add the custom text fields to the checkout page.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="shipping-address-fieldset" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom-field" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Module_Name/js/view/custom-field</item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-field</item>
                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">custom_field</item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

4. Create a new template file, `custom-field.html` in the `view/frontend/web/template` directory of your module, and use it to render the custom text fields.

```
<div class="field custom-field">
    <label class="label" for="custom-field">
        <span>Custom Field</span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" class="input-text" id="custom-field" name="custom_field" data-bind="value: custom_field"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

5. In the `view/frontend/web/js/view/custom-field.js` you can use `knockout.js` bindings to handle the custom field value.

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
    ],
    function (Component, quote) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Module_Name/custom-field'
            },
            initObservable: function () {
                this._super()
                    .observe('custom_field');
                return this;
            },
            /**
             * Send value to the quote
             */
            getCustomFieldValue: function () {
                return this.custom_field();
            },
            /**
             * Send value to the quote
             */
            setCustomFieldValue: function (value) {
                this.custom_field(value);
            },
        });
    }
);
```

6. Once you have added the layout and template files, you should also need to update the `checkout_index_index.xml` file to include the new fields in the shipping address form.
7. To save the value of the custom field you need to override the shipping address model and add the custom field to the data array before saving it.
8. Clear the cache and check that the custom text fields are now present on the checkout page.

*Note that, this is a general approach, you might need to make some adjustments according to your module structure, and also you can use different events to add custom fields in different parts of checkout page.*

Answer (score 1):

Check this link , need to create a module

https://bsscommerce.com/blog/add-magento-custom-checkout-fields/

Answer (score 1):

You can Refer to this blog and create a module:-
**https://blog.magezon.com/how-to-add-field-in-magento-2-checkout-page-mgt/**