Show VAT Number on Shipping Page Magento 2
I want to show VAT Number on Magento 2 Shipping Page only & that too when particular checkbox is checked.
Can someone help me in developing this.
Basically, what I want -
There will be custom checkbox. Once that is checked, VAT Number field should be shown and 1 custom attribute field should be shown. On submit, the data for both the fields should be saved in 'sales_order' and 'quote_address' table.

Rashi Goyal You can check the below given reference links where it is been shown how you can add fields in checkout page. Reference: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/363873/magento2-4-5-how-to-add-custom-text-fields-on-checkout-page https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/367151/how-can-i-add-custom-fields-in-checkout-page
